# .NET WebTest Custom ValidationRules - How to unit test?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, webtest

I'm creating custom ValidationRules for a .NET webtest.

Is there some easy way to create unit tests for these validation rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a database+table for holding webtest values, create a webtest that loads from your table and populates the form with the values from your table. You can also add an "expected result" column. The webtest can then iterate automatically through rows in the table and report success based on the "expected result". A coded webtest is going to be easier to create your custom validation rule with.